# app.js is loaded only after npm run watch laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have installed laravel 5.8. To use vue.js in it I run npm install and then npm run watch. but each time I change the app.js file, I have to run npm run watch to show the changes. Its very annoying to run that command for every little changes.

Some of my codes are given below

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <articles></articles>

  </div>
</div>
```

.........

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell that will be open with `npm run watch` when you are working on your project. This will track your changes whenever you are changing anything. And finally you can use either `npm run dev` or `npm run production`. 
[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix)

Comment: use one shell for `php artisan serve` and use another shell for `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can execute npm run watch then it will never close until you close it manually from terminal.

The changes you do in you file it will automatically affect everywhere

Comment: so you mean, I have to open two command prompt window. one for npm run watch and anohter for php artisan serve??

Comment: Yeah you have to open 2 CMD, well your most welcome, will you please approve the answer, that will helpful to me as well! Lol